# Not able to enter text in a edit field inside a modal/dialog using Teststack/White

Tags: white-framework

I am trying to enter text in a edit field in a modal window. I get an error "Failed to get (ControlType=edit or ControlType=document),AutomationId=1118,ClassName=Edit"

The following is my code.

`var window = app.GetWindow("Toolkit Version");
            Window AuthWindow = null;
            AuthWindow = window.ModalWindow("Please Authenticate");
            TextBox userNameField = AuthWindow.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("Edit").AndAutomationId("1118"));
            userNameField.Text = "Administrator";`

From Inspect

[image]

Error details - 
`TestStack.White.AutomationException: 'Failed to get (ControlType=edit or ControlType=document),AutomationId=1118,ClassName=Edit'`

Any suggestions or workarounds?
Thanks!

Comment: is `AuthWindow` null?

Comment: No, it is not null.

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

1. Perhaps your SearchCriteria are too restrictive? Try:

   ```
   TextBox userNameField = AuthWindow.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("1118"));
   ```

   or even

   ```
   TextBox userNameField = AuthWindow.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("1118")) as TextBox;
   ```
2. It might not be very elegant, but it looks like your window is small and has few controls. Why not picking them this way?

   ```
   TextBox userNameField = AuthWindow.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(System.Windows.Automation.ControlType.Edit)[0]
   ```

I supposed your textbox is at position 0 but of course you can change that.

Comment: TextBox userNameField = AuthWindow.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(System.Windows.Automation.ControlType.Edit)[0]
worked for me! Thank you very much!